# How to know that I passed the firewall from the TCP connections?

Tags: networking, browser, firewall, tcp, session

In my company, in order to access some intranet-sites, I have first to login to webpage (which I suppose is a firewall or something) with my account. If I login from FF for example, I can access the intranet-websites from FF, IE, or chrome. I mean it doesn't have to be from the same browser from which I logged.

Therefore, I suppose that whenever I login to this "FireWall", I should see something in TCP active connections or something on which the browsers know that now I can access those intranet websites. I looked but I wasn't able to see something special (maybe I don't know how to look).

**Update: Clarification:**
I mean if I login to gmail for example in FF, then FF knows that I'm logged from the `cookies`. But other browsers don't.

**Question: How can each browser detect logging from another browser?**

Comment: My assumption is its some proxy server that knows "so and so has logged in successfully from your IP"

Comment: @rogerdpack, thanks for the reply. Is there a way to check this from a CLI command like looking at the TCP connections or something?

Comment: hard to tell, but...I doubt it.  You could use wget from the command line to "get" a restricted page, indicating whether you've been granted access or not, perhaps...

Comment: using `wget` along with what? You mean with this proxy url? or?

Comment: an intranet only site